# No refreshing, every time the same Image

Tags: java, swing

Basically, I am trying to create an app, that displays images.

`filename` variable is a path to an image that I want to display. After I start an app, an Image is displayed, but then, when I remove the image from a hard drive (or change other image to the `filename` name) I don't get any other Image, just the same as before.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {

    String filename = "C:\\temp\\1.jpeg";
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(filename)));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    // Mouse Listener is only to display another JFrame after mouseClicked event
    frame.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            main(args);
        }

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you still get the same image after restarting the app? Or just that it doesn't "see" the deletion?

Comment: No, not after restaring the application. I mean it doesn't see any changes (deletion, changing file). When I click on a frame, it should have created a new frame with a new ImageIcon (or with exception that file doesn't exist), but it just creates new frame the same as previous one.

Comment: A small tip: in the future, when you want to implement only 1 or 2 of `MouseListener`s methods, extend the `MouseAdapter` class instead. That way, you won't have methods with empty bodys anymore...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image is cached. You need to force it to reload by doing either:

```
//  This works using ImageIO

imageLabel.setIcon( new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read( new File(imageName) ) ) );

//  Or you can flush the image

ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(imageName);
icon.getImage().flush();
imageLabel.setIcon( icon );
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is all the code there is, and you are moving files around on the OS, your application will not pick up the changes.

The image has been loaded and will always be told to draw the same way.

You could use a [WatchService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) to watch for changes on the file (I think) or just periodically check to see if the file has changed.

Answer (score 0):

That behaviour you are trying to achieve seems a bit unusual. If that is what you want to do you could set a timer that triggers an event periodically (every "n" seconds or whatever is appropriate), deletes the image icon object and adds a new one. Don't forget to call "pack()" at the end.